# Making .next() element slideToggle correctly with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, slidetoggle

At the moment, The code below only works for one container. I am looking to make only the description associated with that click slideToggle.

jquery:

```
$("#closedImage").click(function(){
    $('#closedImage').css("display", "none");
    $('#openImage').css("display", "block");
    $(this).parent().next(".jobDescription").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("#openImage").click(function(){
    $('#openImage').css("display", "none");
    $('#closedImage').css("display", "block");
    $(this).parent().next(".jobDescription").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

php/html - contents within foreach loop:

```
    echo "<div id=\"theJob\">";
    echo "<a href=\"/job/view/".$job['id']."/".$job['url']."\">";

    echo "<div id=\"leftContain\" class=\"floatLeft\">";
    echo "<h2 class=\"green\">".$job['role']."</h2>";
    echo "<div class=\"blue floatLeft\"><h3>".$job['company']." in ".$job['location']."</h3></div><br><br>";        
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</a>";

    echo "<div id=\"rightContain\" class=\"floatLeft\">";
    echo "<div id=\"closedImage\"><img src=\"/images/side.png\"></div>";    
    echo "<div id=\"openImage\"><img src=\"/images/down.png\"></div>";              
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class=\"jobDescription floatLeft\">";
    echo $job['description'];   
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the html with multiple containers.... not the php code.Are you duplicating the ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are duplicating the ids `closedImage` and `openImage` etc in your containers. instead turn them to/add classnames and try .

```
$(".closedImage").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide().siblings('.openImage').show();; //hide and show are shortcuts to display none / block
    $this.parent().next(".jobDescription").slideToggle("slow");
});

$(".openImage").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide().siblings('.closedImage').show();;
    $this.parent().next(".jobDescription").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

*Use ids sparingly and turn them into classes. Duplicate ids make your html invalid and selectors to fail as they will select the first one appearing in DOM*

Comment: Nice one, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a foreach with ids not classes. The selectors in your jquery will only return the first id it comes across, the rest will be ignored.

IDs should never appear more than once on a page and is invalid markup.

Change the IDs to classes and it should fix your issue :)

Hope this helps.